# HttpClient requests not working for a particular domain in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that sends a request to a URL and sends back the response. This function kept failing with timeout error for URLs from a particular domain (confidential).

To debug this, I created a very minimal Azure function:

```
var content = string.Empty;
using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url))
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    content = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
}
return new OkObjectResult(content);
```

This code works fine in local. When I try using the deployed Azure function, it works for all the other domains I tried (ex: https://google.com) but it hits request timeout error for a particular domain after trying for about 90 seconds. The error happens at this particular line: _httpClient.GetAsync(url). Again, it works fine for this (confidential) domain in local.

I have tried deploying the Azure function to two completely different Azure service plans and regions. Same result. It doesn't work for URLs from the required domain. Works for URLs of other domains.

Error:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
```

**Update (solution):**

I tried sending a request from Postman, copied the code from there for C# and deployed it to the Azure function and it is now working for the problematic domain. Something like below:

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

The key here is `client.Timeout = -1`, which seems to have fixed the problem.

Now, in my original code, I tried setting HttpClient's timeout to Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan both in Startup configuration as well as at individual request level but it did not work.

```
services.AddHttpClient("AzureTestClient", options =>
{
    options.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
});
```

Am I setting the timeout wrong in the HttpClient solution?

Comment: Have you tried calling the URL for example from an Azure VM?

Comment: @silent I haven't tried from an Azure VM. I tried a URL ping test from AppInsights Availability and that returned success response.

Comment: Guess: that server is blocking all requests from Azure IP address ranges, due to spam.

Comment: @IanKemp I tried tcpping for the problematic domain as well as curl for the URL from Console of the AppService. Both worked.

Comment: Can you provide more info about the Service Plan you have? Also for the confidential domain, does it use a self signed certificate?

Comment: @BassamGamal The service plan for the App Service is PremiumV2 and for the Azure function, it is Consumption. The confidential domain uses DigiCert certificate.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using a Consumption plan then maybe the confidential URL need to whitelist the whole Azure Data center. You can follow the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses) or consider upgrading the Consumption plan to a [premium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#premium-plan) one and have a dedicated linked VNET.
   Maybe your local machine is already linked to the domain/whitelisted so azure function operates from different range.
2. Another reason maybe the URL returns a different HttpStatusCode that is't Successful range (200-299) so it fails with "EnsureSuccessStatusCode" in the old code?

Normally for the http code initialization, I did something like that:

```
public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("AzureTestClient",
            options => { options.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan; });
    }
```

Then when I want to use it, I do like that in any other function and it worked:

```
var client = clientFactory.CreateClient("AzureTestClient");
```